# Cannot get cx_oracle variable to bind properly when using it in to_date function

Tags: python-2.7, data-binding, cx-oracle

I am trying to replace this call:

```
cursor = connection.cursor()
try:
    sql = "select m.lat, m.longt, v.tmax from vcsn_view v, vcsn_metadata m where set_vcsn('local_day=to_date(20180304)-1') is null and v.agent_no = m.agent_no(+) order by 1,2"
    cursor.execute(sql)
    for lat, longt, tmax in cursor:
        print("Values:", lat, longt, tmax)
except cx_Oracle.DatabaseError, e:
    printf ('Failed to select\n')
    printException(e)
    exit(1)
```

with a call that takes the date in the query as variable, ie:

```
cursor = connection.cursor()
try:
    sql = "select m.lat, m.longt, v.tmax from vcsn_view v, vcsn_metadata m where set_vcsn('local_day=to_date(:1)-1') is null and v.agent_no = m.agent_no(+) order by 1,2"
    cursor.execute(sql, (20180304,))
    for lat, longt, tmax in cursor:
        print("Values:", lat, longt, tmax)
except cx_Oracle.DatabaseError, e:
    printf ('Failed to select\n')
    printException(e)
    exit(1)
```

But I cannot get it to work. I get the error:
    Failed to select
    Error code = 1036
    Error message = ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your SQL you have the :1 inside quotes so it won't work. I'm not sure if set_vcsn() requires a string. Assuming that it does, you need to do the following:cursor = connection.cursor()

```
try:
    sql = "select m.lat, m.longt, v.tmax from vcsn_view v, vcsn_metadata m where set_vcsn('local_day=to_date(' || :1 || ')-1') is null and v.agent_no = m.agent_no(+) order by 1,2"
    cursor.execute(sql, (20180304,))
    for lat, longt, tmax in cursor:
        print("Values:", lat, longt, tmax)
except cx_Oracle.DatabaseError, e:
    printf ('Failed to select\n')
    printException(e)
    exit(1)
```

If set_vcsn() doesn't require a string, then it would be helpful to provide a bit more information if you need further help. But in general, values inside strings are not searched for bind variables!

Comment: That did it thanx a bunch!. I had an inkling that the problem had to do with set_vcsn(..) function requiring a string, but I could not find anywhere how to escape the bind variable.